# Laravel query string into api call in routes

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route

```
Route::get('/getLocation/{postalCode}', function () {
    $response = Http::get('https://theapi');
    return $response->json();
});
```

Sadly this doesn't work

I can reach the api with

```
https://theapi?PostalCode=xxxx
```

How can i replicate this in my route to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got double }} there, try delete it so it will be like this:

```
Route::get('/getLocation/{postalCode}', function () {
    $response = Http::get('https://theapi');
    return $response->json();
});
```

Edit:

Add the route parameter to API function parameters

```
Route::get('/getLocation/{postalCode}', function ($postalCode) {
    // do whatever you want to postalCode variable
    $response = Http::get('https://theapi', [
        'PostalCode' => $postalCode
    ]);
    return $response->json();
});
```

Comment: doesn't work, i need to send the postal code as parameter to the api. I think i need to pass the value in the route, access to it inside this function and send on the api call

Comment: I can access the variable now, your example will be correct if you edit it to send this variable to the API in the parameters. Tested and works

Comment: edited your question so others can see the working example

Comment: Reminder, if you need more than one variable later, the parameter for the function will follow the route parameter order, naming isn't important except you are using binding